# MySQL : Get duplicate data for duplicate query fields

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to mySQL and PHP, so bear with me.

How can I make it so that if my query has duplicate fields, the data retrieved would have repeated data for the repeated query fields.

An example would be like:

query for id = 34, 54, 21, 21, 50 (already in the order I want them to be in)

I want the database to return

user_icon for id = 34, user_icon for id = 54, user_icon for id = 21, user_icon for id = 21, and user_icon for id = 50.

And not just one data returned for the duplicate id 21.

Here is the code I am using at the moment:

```
 $thumb = "SELECT thumbnail from users WHERE id IN (".$idsearch.") ORDER BY FIELD(id , ".$idsearch.")";
   $search = $con->prepare($thumb);
   $search -> execute();

   $pics = $search->fetchAll();
   foreach($pics as $pic) {
     $thumbnail[] = $pic['thumbnail'];
  }
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: If you really need the value/result twice you should assign it twice in php after fetching from db. You could get it twice from db i.e. by querying each id seperatly or doing a union but that all doesn't really make sense. Best way would be not even assigning it twice but using the right variable at the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to think of a MYSQL query right now. But if perfomance is not of a concern, you can use some thing like

```
$thumb = "SELECT thumbnail from users WHERE id = ?";
$search = $con->prepare($thumb);

foreach($idsearch as $id) {
   $search->execute(array($id));
   $pics = $search->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   $search->closeCursor();
   $thumbnail[] = $pic['thumbnail'];
}
```

PDO will compile the SQL Query and the execution will be faster than a normal sql query.

Answer (score 0):

An SQL query returns every row in the table that matches the `where` condition. If you want to filter duplicates out, it requires you to explicitly do that (e.g., by using the `distinct` keyword).
Since your query does not have any such special treatment, it will return duplicates if they exist, so your code is fine.